# Combine two lua scripts that switch with mouse key

Tags: lua, macros, accessibility, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I like to combine these two lua scripts that let you switch between each function with mouse key

This one type "a" every 2000ms

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
        repeat  
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
    repeat



            PressKey("a")
Sleep(100)
ReleaseKey("a")
Sleep(2000)



                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end         


        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end     
    end
end
```

This one type "H" every 2000ms

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
        repeat  
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
    repeat



            PressKey("h")
Sleep(100)
ReleaseKey("h")
Sleep(2000)



                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)

        end         


        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end     
    end
end
```

How do i achieve this ?

Thanks

I tried to use IsKeyLockOn with another key for the 2nd script but both failed to work.

https://douile.com/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Introduce variable `key` and change its value from "a" to "h" then again to "a" and so on on each mouse button 6 press:

```
-- Mouse Button 6 switches between `a` and `h`

local key = "a"
local next_key = { a = "h",  h = "a" }

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then 
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then 
        key = next_key[key]
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsKeyLockOn"numlock" then 
        repeat
            PressKey(key)
            Sleep(100)
            ReleaseKey(key)
            local tm = GetRunningTime() + 2000
            repeat
                Sleep(10)
                if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end
            until GetRunningTime() > tm 
        until nil
    end
end
```